# How to pull account data from MetaTrader?

Tags: next.js, forex

I need a solution so users can connect to their account through a website using their account details to pull accounts data.

Or an ea like fxblue or MetaTrader?

I’ve looked into websockets and zeromq which is a solution

Does anyone have experience with this?